# Angular2 parsing error usng ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the ngFor directive in an angular 2 (alpha 35) application, however I seem to continually get the error **EXCEPTION: Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of the '' element and there are no matching directives with a corresponding property**

I have seen other posts on Stack Overflow with a similar issue, however, in those cases, the programmer has either used dashed casing or all loweercase.  In my case, I have ensured that the casing is correct:

```
<div *ngFor="#t of rummyGame.ComputerHand.Cards">{{t}}</div>
```

Despite this, I am always getting the above error (I have tested in both Chrome and FF)

Answer (score 1):

In this old version it was

```
ng-for
```

current is beta.17

In beta.17 it is

```
<div *ngFor="let t of rummyGame.ComputerHand.Cards">{{t}}</div>
```